# Is there a way to avoid "Magic Number" issues when I know the destination plateform?

Tags: python, cross-compiling, magic-numbers

I built a tool in python 2.7.5 and I compiled it with `python -m compileall`

When I tried to use it on the destination plateforme (python 2.6.6) I got that annoying "Magic Number" error.

I already read a bunch of things about that error and I think I understand whats happening...

Then my question is : Is there a way to specify the "target platform" when I compile the `.py` files or should I downgrade my current version of python to match the "production" one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot cross-compile for other Python versions, no.

Just install Python 2.6 *next to Python 2.7* and use `compileall` with that to produce your bytecode files instead. You can install multiple versions of Python quite painlessly.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it, just looking for the best way to install it on fedora :-p

Comment: @PatrickFerreira: I use https://github.com/collective/buildout.python to quickly build all major Python versions in one place.